# Show there exists a continuous function $0\leq f\leq 1$ vanishing off a rectangle.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, normed-spaces

Am trying to extend the following result to rectangles $C,C'\subset\mathbb R^d$.

**Proposition.** Let $C,C'$ be cubes with nonempty interiors in $\mathbb R^d$, such that $C'$ extends each edge of $C$ both ways. Then there exists a continuous function $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ such that $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f=1$ on $C$, and $f$ vanishes off $C'$.

**Proof**. WLOG let $C=[a_1,b_1]\times\dots\times [a_d,b_d]$ and $C'=[a_1-\epsilon,b_1+\epsilon]\times\dots\times [a_d-\epsilon,b_d+\epsilon]$, where $\frac{b_i-a_i}{2}:=l>0$ for each $i$, and $\epsilon>0$. Let $u:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be the function which is equal to $1$ on $[-l,l]$, vanishes off $[-l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon]$, and is affine on $[-l-\epsilon,-l]$ and $[l,l+\epsilon]$. Let $f:\mathbb R^d\to \mathbb R$ be defined by $$x\mapsto f(x):=u(\|x-m\|_{\infty}),$$

where $m:=\Big(\frac{a_1+b_1}{2},\dots,\frac{a_d+b_d}{2}\Big)$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ is the max norm on $\mathbb R^d$. Since $u$ and $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$ are continuous, $f$ is continuous. Moreover, we have that $0\leq f\leq 1$, $f=1$ on $C$, and $f=0$ outside $C'$.

Any ideas on how to generalize to rectangles? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Note $C,C'\in \mathbb R^d$ is incorrect notation.

Comment: @zhw thank you I corrected the mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. Given $E \subset X$ closed and $U \supset E$ open, there exists a continuous function $f \colon X \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $0 \leq f \leq 1$ on $X$, $f = 1$ on $E$, and $f = 0$ off $U$. Namely
$$f(x) = \frac{d(x, U^c)}{d(x, E) + d(x, U^c)}.$$
This is enough to prove your proposition since $C \subset \text{int}(C')$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I believe the denominator of $f$ is never zero because $d(x, U^c)=0$ implies $x\in U^c$ which implies $x\notin E$ and then $d(x,E)\neq 0$ since $E$ is closed. This also shows that $d(x, U^c)\neq 0$ if $x\in E$.

Comment: @Alphie Yes I am using the fact that if $A \subset X$, then for all $x \in X$, $$d(x, A) = 0 \iff x \in \overline{A}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you can prove it for cubes, you can prove it for rectangles as follows. Firstly, let $A : \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be an affine transformation taking your rectangle $R$ to the unit cube $C = [0,1]^n.$ $A(R')$ is then some rectangle extending the sides of $C$. Look at the smallest cube extending $C$ which is contained in $A(R'),$ and call it $C'$ (this cube is formed basically by looking at how far you extended the sides of $C$ to get $A(R'),$ and then just extending each side by the minimum of those amounts). Then apply your lemma to the cube; obviously the function $f$ will then be 1 on $C,$ and 0 outside of $C'\subseteq A(R').$ Taking $g = f \circ A,$ you get a function which is 1 on $R$ and zero outside of $R'.$

Comment: Am I right in saying that the map defined coordinatewise by $x_i\mapsto \frac{1}{b_i-a_i}(x_i-a_i)$ $i=1,\dots,d$ is suitable for $A$? Also at the end isn't $g = f \circ A$? The claim that $A$ is zero outside $R'$ uses the fact that $A$ is invertible no?

Comment: @Alphie Yeah, you want $f\circ A,$ my bad. And you do use injectivity of $A$ (it is also invertible, but I don't think you need surjectiivty) to see that $f\circ A$ is zero outside of $R'$.

Comment: Thank you. Is this choice of $A$ the only one possible? Do you think my proof for the cube case is ok?